# How to rotate bitmap with duration for Splash Activity?

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I've created SplashActivity for my app. (styles.xml)

```
 <!-- Splash Screen theme. -->
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
 </style>
```

(SplashActivity.java)

```
package com.example.danilochagov.todo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish(); // close this activity
    }
}
```

(AndroidManifest.xml)

```
  <!-- preloader (splash) activity -->
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:name="com.example.danilochagov.todo.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

(splash_background.xml in drawable folder)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" /> <!-- color blue -->

   <item>
       <bitmap
           android:src="@drawable/preloader_1" <!-- photo -->
           android:gravity="center" />

   </item>
 </layer-list>
```

And after it I have preloader as a photo with backgroud color blue. But how can I do so that my photo will rotate there and with animation(duration)?

Comment: apply rotate animation on bitmap and when animation end then call finish()

Answer (score 0):

first of all turn your xml to a simple Relative Layout with an imageView.then put your intent in your splash activity in a Handler Like This :

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //your Intent goes Here 
        }
    },TIME);
```

Then Create A animation file like this in your res/anim folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="5000" />
```

beware that your duration in animation.xml should be the same as TIME in Splash Class

Then apply animation to your image

```
 ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.img);
        AnimationSet animationSet = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.youranimxml);
        img.setAnimation(animationSet);
        animationSet.start();
```

Comment: I know this way, but if I do it my preloader will work the specific time and I want to add preloader which will work the time that need